# How to change background color of text field when selecting another tab?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Tab Controller with four tabs. On two of the tabs, I have text fields that have data validation. If the data validation fails, it changes the background color to red. However, when I switch to another tab and come back to the tab with data validation, the text field still has a red background. How can I change the background color of the text field after leaving the tab with data validation?

I have tried adding this to `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.textName.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

I have tried

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, 
  didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
      let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
      if tabBarIndex == 1 {
        self.textName.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

Neither of these approaches work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it inside `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` as `viewDidLoad` is called once when the VC is Loaded

```
self.textName.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

for `didSelect` , you need

```
self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
```